# How to improve this SELECT?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Can this select somehow be rewritten to execute faster? What would you suggest? Where to start looking for...? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I don't understand why there is "TABLE ACCESS FULL" in the line 19 of the execution plan because COL7 is PK in T1 ("ba") and in T6 ("bba") has a unique index (combined index with 1 more column).

Also, T2 didn't had an index on COL4 so I added it, but the execution plan is the same. Nothing changed. Still full table scan at lines 21 and 22. Why?

```
SELECT pcl.COL1,
       pcl.COL2,
       pcl.COL3,
       pcl.COL4,
       (SELECT cc.COL5
          FROM T3 cc
          JOIN T4 cvp
            ON cvp.COL10 = cc.COL10
           AND cvp.COL2 = pcl.COL2) AS COL10,
       pp.COL11
FROM T1 ba
JOIN T2 pcl
  ON pcl.COL1 = ba.COL1
 AND (pcl.COL2 = ba.COL2 OR ba.COL2 = 0)
JOIN T5 pscl
  ON pscl.COL2 = pcl.COL2
 AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
 AND (pscl.COL6 = ba.COL6 OR ba.COL6 = 'ALL')
LEFT JOIN T6 bba
  ON bba.COL7 = ba.COL7
LEFT JOIN T7 bsa
  ON bsa.COL7 = ba.COL7
LEFT JOIN T8 pp
  ON pp.COL1 = pcl.COL1
WHERE (ba.COL8 = 617617 OR bsa.COL8 = 617617 OR bba.COL9 = 617617)
 AND ba.COL4 <> 3
 AND pcl.COL4 <> 3
 AND pscl.COL4 <> 3
 AND NOT EXISTS
(SELECT *
       FROM T1 ba2
      WHERE ba2.COL1 = ba.COL1
        AND ((ba2.COL2 = pcl.COL2 AND
            (ba2.COL6 = pscl.COL6 OR ba2.COL6 = 'ALL')) OR
            (ba.COL6 = 'ALL' AND ba.COL2 = 0 AND ba2.COL6 = pscl.COL6))
        AND (ba2.COL2 <> ba.COL2 OR ba2.COL2 = 0)
        AND ba2.COL13 = ba.COL13
        AND ba2.COL12 = ba.COL12
        AND ba2.COL4 <> 3)
UNION (SELECT pcl.COL1,
           pcl.COL2,
           pcl.COL3,
           pcl.COL4,
           (SELECT cc.COL5
              FROM T3 cc
              JOIN T4 cvp
                ON cvp.COL10 = cc.COL10
               AND cvp.COL2 = pcl.COL2) AS COL10,
           pp.COL11
      FROM T9 sa
      LEFT JOIN T2 pcl
        on sa.COL1 = pcl.COL1
       and (sa.COL2 = pcl.COL2 or sa.COL2 = 0)
       and (sa.COL14 = pcl.COL14)
       and pcl.COL4 <> 6
       and pcl.COL4 is not null
       AND pcl.COL3 is not null
      LEFT JOIN T8 pp
        on pp.COL1 = pcl.COL1
     WHERE sa.COL8 = 617617
       AND pcl.COL14 = 100805)
ORDER BY COL11, COL1, COL4, COL3;
```

Version of the DB is Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name                                   | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem |  O/1/M   |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                                        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64899 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  SORT UNIQUE                            |                                        |      1 |   4136K|      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64899 |  2048 |  2048 |     1/0/0|
|   2 |   UNION-ALL                             |                                        |      1 |        |     27 |00:00:00.71 |   64899 |       |       |          |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                                        |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T4                                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       5 |       |       |          |
|*  5 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_VPCCONT                           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T3                                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       2 |       |       |          |
|*  7 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_SYSCONCA                          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       1 |       |       |          |
|*  8 |    FILTER                               |                                        |      1 |        |     27 |00:00:00.71 |   64888 |       |       |          |
|   9 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                                        |      1 |   5940K|     27 |00:00:00.71 |   64885 |       |       |          |
|  10 |      NESTED LOOPS                       |                                        |      1 |   5940K|     81 |00:00:00.71 |   64861 |       |       |          |
|  11 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER                |                                        |      1 |   7702 |      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64857 |       |       |          |
|* 12 |        HASH JOIN                        |                                        |      1 |   7702 |      1 |00:00:00.89 |   64853 |   962K|   962K|     1/0/0|
|* 13 |         FILTER                          |                                        |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.25 |   38012 |       |       |          |
|* 14 |          HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER          |                                        |      1 |  16426 |   1645K|00:00:00.84 |   38012 |  2920K|  2920K|     1/0/0|
|  15 |           VIEW                          | index$_join$_011                       |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 16 |            HASH JOIN                    |                                        |      1 |        |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |  2078K|  2078K|     1/0/0|
|  17 |             INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | I_FK_BUSTLACC_SETTACC_COL8             |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|  18 |             INDEX FAST FULL SCAN        | I_UK_BUSTLACC_COL7_AMOUNTTYPE          |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 19 |           HASH JOIN RIGHT OUTER         |                                        |      1 |   1641K|   1645K|00:00:00.54 |   38008 |    24M|  4789K|     1/0/0|
|  20 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T6                                     |      1 |    414K|    413K|00:00:00.01 |    1634 |       |       |          |
|* 21 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL            | T1                                     |      1 |   1632K|   1636K|00:00:00.28 |   36374 |       |       |          |
|* 22 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL               | T2                                     |      1 |   1100K|   1102K|00:00:00.16 |   26841 |       |       |          |
|  23 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | T8                                     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 24 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | I_PK_PARTNER                           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 25 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | I_FK_PCSUBLIN_CONTRACT_COL2            |      1 |      8 |     81 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 26 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | T5                                     |     81 |    771 |     27 |00:00:00.01 |      24 |       |       |          |
|* 27 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | T1                                     |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 28 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | I_BUSIACC_COL1_3C                      |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|  29 |    NESTED LOOPS                         |                                        |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  30 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T4                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 31 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_VPCCONT                           |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  32 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T3                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 33 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_SYSCONCA                          |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  34 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                   |                                        |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|  35 |     NESTED LOOPS                        |                                        |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 36 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID        | T9                                     |      1 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 37 |       INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                 | I_PK_SETTACC                           |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 38 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| T2                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 39 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | I_PARCONLI_PID_PARTNERMCC              |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|  40 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID         | T8                                     |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
|* 41 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                  | I_PK_PARTNER                           |      0 |      1 |      0 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   5 - access("CVP"."COL2"=:B1)
   7 - access("CVP"."COL10"="CC"."COL10")
   8 - filter( IS NULL)
  12 - access("PCL"."COL1"="BA"."COL1")
       filter(("PCL"."COL2"="BA"."COL2" OR "BA"."COL2"=0))
  13 - filter(("BA"."COL8"=617617 OR "BSA"."COL8"=617617 OR "BBA"."COL9"=617617))
  14 - access("BSA"."COL7"="BA"."COL7")
  16 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  19 - access("BBA"."COL7"="BA"."COL7")
  21 - filter("BA"."COL4"<>3)
  22 - filter("PCL"."COL4"<>3)
  24 - access("PP"."COL1"="PCL"."COL1")
  25 - access("PSCL"."COL2"="PCL"."COL2")
  26 - filter(("PSCL"."COL4"<>3 AND ("PSCL"."COL6"="BA"."COL6" OR "BA"."COL6"='ALL')))
  27 - filter(("BA2"."COL12"=:B1 AND "BA2"."COL13"=:B2 AND "BA2"."COL4"<>3))
  28 - access("BA2"."COL1"=:B1)
       filter((((:B1='ALL' AND :B2=0 AND "BA2"."COL6"=:B3) OR ("BA2"."COL2"=:B4 AND INTERNAL_FUNCTION("BA2"."COL6"))) AND 
              ("BA2"."COL2"<>:B5 OR "BA2"."COL2"=0)))
  31 - access("CVP"."COL2"=:B1)
  33 - access("CVP"."COL10"="CC"."COL10")
  36 - filter("SA"."COL14"=100805)
  37 - access("SA"."COL8"=617617)
  38 - filter(("PCL"."COL14"=100805 AND ("SA"."COL2"="PCL"."COL2" OR "SA"."COL2"=0) AND "PCL"."COL4"<>6))
  39 - access("SA"."COL1"="PCL"."COL1")
  41 - access("PP"."COL1"="PCL"."COL1")
```

Table and column names are carefully anonymized. I hope that you don't mind.

Comment: First things first. The query is malformed. The predicate `bsa.COL8 = 617617` defeats the outer join, silently converting it into an inner join. There are around six more predicated with the same issue. Please fix the query.

Comment: A you can see, all with indexes works very fast. The most terrible problems are with tables T1, T2 and T6 - all they have acces by `TABLE ACCESS FULL` - this is very bad. Of course, they should have indexes, but conditions for this really strange... `(ba.COL8 = 617617 OR bsa.COL8 = 617617 OR bba.COL9 = 617617)`, `ba.COL4 <> 3`, etc... it's really horror... OR in the SQL is very bad solution in any cases.

Comment: Nobody can look at an execution plan without any knowledge of the data and say it's bad. Every step in that plan could be exactly the correct decision by the optimizer given a certain set of data volumes and cardinalities. Oracle isn't in the business of generating a plan that is always-bad in all situations, or they'd be horrid programmers. To determine what's wrong, you'd have to know how many rows each step of the plan is outputting, and look for where Oracle's cardinality estimate is way off and where all the time is being spent. For that I'd recommend a SQL Monitor report.

Comment: Run your query with the GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS hint and then issue: select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST')).  That will give an alternative plan representation that will be much more useful for us to help you with

Comment: @ConnorMcDonald I added above the execution plan using GATHER_PLAN_STATISTICS.

Comment: I don't understand why there is "TABLE ACCESS FULL" in the line 19 of the execution plan because COL7 is PK in T1 ("ba") and has unique index (together with 1 more column) in T6 ("bba").

Comment: @TheImpaler Yes, you are right: OR is the issue. If I keep only bba.COL9 = 617617 then it executes 20x faster, but I need all 3 of them (ba.COL8 = 617617 OR bsa.COL8 = 617617 OR bba.COL9 = 617617).  How can I fix my SQL?

Comment: @FriendlyDragon Yes, you are right: OR is the issue. If I keep only bba.COL9 = 617617 then it executes 20x faster, but I need all 3 of them (ba.COL8 = 617617 OR bsa.COL8 = 617617 OR bba.COL9 = 617617). How can I fix my SQL?

Comment: @DaniChe if you need all this data, maybe it have a sence to prepare 3 different queries without operator OR and union them by UNION operator? It is not a perfect solution, but I think you will be able to reach your goals.

Comment: @FriendlyDragon Yes, thank you. At the end I used UNION. Great idea! If you post it as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, all with indexes works very fast. The most terrible problems are with tables T1, T2 and T6 - all they have acces by `TABLE ACCESS FULL` - this is very bad.

Of course, they should have indexes, but conditions for this really strange... `(ba.COL8 = 617617 OR bsa.COL8 = 617617 OR bba.COL9 = 617617), ba.COL4 <> 3,`

As we discassed in comments, it can be a root of issue, so, to avoid `FULL ACCESS` and if you need exactly one of these values, you can use `UNION`, something like this.

If you have some `OR` like this for case1:

```sql
with q as (
    select   id, name
    from     table
    where    id in (5, 6, 7)
)
select   *
from     q
```

you can transform it to something like this for case2:

```sql
with q as (
    select   id, name
    from     table
    where    id = 5
    union all
    select   id, name
    from     table
    where    id = 6
    union all
    select   id, name
    from     table
    where    id = 7
)
select   *
from     q
```

So, in case 2 database will be able use indexes for your tables.